# How to correctly infer the type of a key with direct key access and generic interface in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to get TypeScript to correctly infer the types that are valid in the following context:

I have 2 interfaces

```
interface A {
  first: string;
}

type B = {
  second: string;
}
```

as well as a generic interface that has 2 mappers where the types depend on each other, something like

```
interface Gen<T extends string> {
  firstMapper: () => T;
  callback(arg: T): string;
}
```

I want also to have an interface that records multiple `Gen` interfaces

```
interface Aobject {
  "a": Gen<"a">,
  "b": Gen<"b">,
}
```

Finally, I want to create function that takes a key of `AObject`, retrieves the configuration from the `AObject` interface calls the `firstMapper` and then the `callback` such as:

```
const buildMapping = (configKey: keyof Aobject, arg: Aobject) => {
  const myA: Aobject = {
    "a": {
      firstMapper: () => "a",
      callback: (input) => ("result" + input)
    },
    "b": {
      firstMapper: () => "b",
      callback: (input) => ("result" + input)
    }
  }

  const selected = myA[configKey];
  selected.callback(selected.firstMapper());
}
```

However, when I try to do this, **I have an error**

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

However, if I change to this

```
  if (configKey === "a") {
    const selected = myA[configKey]
  selected.callback(selected.firstMapper())
  }
  if (configKey === "b") {
    const selected = myA[configKey]
    selected.callback(selected.firstMapper())
  }
```

**there is no error.**

My understanding is that Typescript does not understand that if the `configKey` is of type `"b"`, then `selected` can only have the type

```
b {
   firstMapper: () => "b",
   callback: (input) => ("result" + input)
}
```

instead TS "thinks" that the callback can be called with both and tries to create the intersection of type `"a"` and type `"b"` which results in `never`.

I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this use case, because I find it weird having to write an `if` case executing the same piece of code.

I tried to create a more generic interface because I thought the problem might come from the `AObject` definition but no success.

I created a [small playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnJsKAZzAC5lipQBzAbiwF8sswBPABxQCFkBeTHchAQB7EABMyFanUZNQkWIhQBxCCAA8AFWQQAHpHGFyYSiCoA+frnxEwAWThsOUMgAoAlL0ua6uBHAAbAIAjRABrVzgoKjJNd0kTaQYmLHloeCQ0YWCAKyEwK2QAIjgislUNEqLzABoBIuCy5Ar1Buq62REQYmRggFdgALEHJ2peZFcu-CoAaQgWMjD54Rgs3Pya5CiYtbyEME8eS2w-UR6AWxZUMlRsvYK+E9xi0rIn57wCYhHnN0PLKp1D5+QIhcJuUBsPoHLwTIpQCCEPoBMBFZAAamQkOh7gEuHoQOebTeeOeNm+jl+E3+xUahI+-iCoQQYQhIChMKOcIRSJRaMx2IOpMY+KYp26BUIEAC+QgYnGl1QAG0psBZvMALoCKUy-ZygB0jLBLNcOtlYn15PslOgHk8AHp7cgAKJQKDCKBirGrSaiaZzFi8Hh8Kqed7ILo9M16+V8RUqv1qgNaj7RyAWo3MiJpg1Wn629wOp0AOWEOjdHoEIu9E1V6sDwZDjTDpMjkul5oVVwTIH9mtJOYzoKzpo7MctX2tTgLReQpfL7s9ovoQA) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) approach like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGdkow) work for you? If so, I can write that up as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would work but I would like to avoid "forcing" the types with casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to satisfy the compiler:

1. You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

   [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2AeAKlCAPYCAmBnKuwATgJbwDmAfFALxQDeAUFFAGYlGECyAhmJEQBcUABQBKWtWQBuZlADGPADZKARj3kBrETyLlhyMcMKkKsgL6zGoSFACCAe1UArCPOC0GcnsLhIARDz+lLIsqr4IiP6qwRZWrACu8O4kDvBQqgkkSti8-GTkiADSaJg4+JoQIA6s9k6u7pQicvJp7ORFVcJFADTeesKOLm7AfRJMLK3whAQQSiMQ2J665ADaU+2dIAC6UDz4fsUhcgD0JywXl1fXNxcAeg+Pj3K4cwvYAHSKKupaIq-zdyLD7sTjAPICcRiCyMIA)

   ```ts
   type Gen<T extends string> = {
     firstMapper: () => T;
     callback(arg: T): string;
   };

   type Aobject = {
     a: Gen<"a">;
     b: Gen<"b">;
   };

   function buildMapping<K extends keyof Aobject>(
     configKey: K,
     arg: Aobject,
   ) {
     const selected = arg[configKey] as Gen<K>;
     //                              ^^^^^^^^^
     selected.callback(selected.firstMapper());
   }
   ```
2. You can define the type `Aobject` as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) and the compiler will infer correctly without the assertion. The resulting type is the same:

   [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2AeAKlCAPYCAmBnKuwATgJbwDmAfFALxQDeAUFFAGYlGECyAhmJEQBcUABQBKWtWQBuZlADGPADZKARj3kBrETyLlhyMcMKkKsgL6zGoSFACCAe1UArCPOC0GUANoBlYlBkUABEPMFQAD4hqsEAusJwSP5E1JZyUAD0GQB6APyMjKwArvDuJA7wUKpFJErYvPxk5IgA0miYOPiaECAOrPZOru6UInLyFezkLT3CLQA0crr6Ay5uwAsSTCzj8IQEEEprENieS947k9MgsbIsuAdH2AB0iirqWiL3h+7HT+ycwAaAnEYgsjCAA)

   ```ts
   type Gen<T extends string> = {
     firstMapper: () => T;
     callback(arg: T): string;
   };

   type Aobject = { [Str in "a" | "b"]: Gen<Str> };
     //^? type Aobject = { a: Gen<"a">; b: Gen<"b">; }

   function buildMapping<K extends keyof Aobject>(
     configKey: K,
     arg: Aobject,
   ) {
     const selected = arg[configKey];
     selected.callback(selected.firstMapper());
   }
   ```

Comment: The second solution you suggested works perfectly in the simplified case that i had artificially created. In fact my real use case is a bit more complicated as I would like to define a type that depends on the key

```
interface Gen<T extends string, U> {
  firstMapper: () => T;
  callback :(arg: T) => U;
  secondCallback: (arg: U) => string
}

interface Aobject {
  "a": Gen<"a", A>,
  "b": Gen<"b", B>,
}
```

Comment: I created a playground here: [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKv7zm) @jsejcksn

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216335/how-to-correctly-infer-the-type-of-a-key-with-direct-key-access-and-generic-inte/76220135?noredirect=1#comment134414013_76220135) @Dynamia Well, that kind of substantial revision becomes different question — [editing the current question wouldn't be appropriate because it changes the meaning/scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), but you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you choose to do so, please be sure to include a [mre] in the new post (with your real code) to avoid another similar situation.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216335/how-to-correctly-infer-the-type-of-a-key-with-direct-key-access-and-generic-inte/76220135?noredirect=1#comment134414071_76220135) @Dynamia Here's an example solution to the new code you showed using an assertion: https://tsplay.dev/w29EjW